# Is there a way to store part of a 16 bit value in an 8 bit variable in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, variables, cpu-registers, x86

I created one variable that stores a 16 bit variable, and I'm tring to store the upper half in an 8 bit variable.
How do I do this?

EDIT: its for the IA-32, and I don't think i can use registers

EDIT2: I am allowed to use registers.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blivid&defid=2121658

Comment: How can you possibly write assembly without using registers? That is like trying to add without using arithmetic.

Comment: Is it for a particular CPU (e.g. a Z80 or the Cell processor's SPU) or for some abstract CPU?

Comment: @Crashworks: or like trying to have sex without using genitalia.

Comment: on IA-32 you can not `mov` memory to memory

Comment: OK, I finally understood what the question was asking. Sorry for the confusion. I CAN use registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
mov AX, [var16]
mov [var8], AH
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the SHR, SHL or ROR and ROL to shift of rotate the bits in your register.